# Power Query open 365 Workbooks

Tags: excel, sharepoint, powerquery

I have simple job timesheets stored in SharePoint open on a couple of factory computers in Excel browser mode. They are input to all day so want to leave them open. As they are typing the sheet is saying it is saved and looking in the SharePoint file explorer it says 'Last Saved a few seconds ago' by 'Factory Computer 1'. There is a sheet per week, all in the same folder, both factory teams work off the same sheet each week on different physical computers with different 365 logins.

We have a separate sheet in get office which acts as a dashboard. Power Query successfully pulls in data from the SharePoint but misses any changes since the last refresh if the Timesheet hasn't been closed and reopened in the factory. Are we missing a sync setting somewhere, as I would expect each incremental autosave change to be able to be pulled immediately by PQ?

Thanks

Comment: As per my experience, Sync is not done in real-time. It has a delay. I would try to develop a Power Automate solution to add the data to the dashboard file and see if it works.

Comment: Thanks Ricardo, I'll have to look into Power Automate, not heard of it before